# Nonesenical Times in GTFS file

Tags: gtfs

I am working on a GTFS file and came across these lines concering the time (hh:mm:ss):

[image]

which just make no sense at all.
How am i meant to interpret this? Is this just a mistake or is it part of the specification?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is part of the spec.  Agencies are allowed to specify times after midnight for a given service date if it matches their operational model.

> For times occurring after midnight on the service day, enter the time as a value greater than 24:00:00 in HH:MM:SS local time for the day on which the trip schedule begins.

As an example, let's say an agency operates late-night service on Saturday's.  The service might extend beyond midnight into the next day (Sunday).  To make things easier for modeling these trips, they often get modeled relative to the Saturday service date with a time after 24:00:00.

Comment: if anyone ever comes across this post, it might be a good idea to read the spec sheet: https://developers.google.com/transit/gtfs/reference . I didn't know gtfs was made by google so I had truble finding it